# Stripe throwing an unknown error - Status 400

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I set up the payment gateway using Stripe. but for some unknown reason, it is throwing up an error.

Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_0TGBfaSh8o6dTn) Invalid object thrown in stripe-php-master\lib\Exception\ApiErrorException.php

Here is my code

```
<?php

require("payment-config.php");

\Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);

$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$customer_name = $_POST['customer_name'];
$customer_email = $_POST['customer_email'];
$customer_address = $_POST['customer_address'];


$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      "name"=>$customer_name,
      "email"=>$customer_email,
      "address"=>$customer_address,
      "source"=>$token
));

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
     "amount"=>500,
     "currency"=>"usd",
     "description"=>"easy-accounting",
     "customer"=> $customer->id
));


?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);` this is wrong on so many levels. Fix your server CA bundle.

Comment: As for your other problem, I suggest you consult this API's documentation or support resources to see what fields and values it is expecting in a request. You may want to learn about `try`/`catch` as well.

Comment: I'm testing this on localhost. That's why I disabled SSL @miken32

Comment: Then it should be even easier for you to correctly configure your CA bundle.

Comment: Okay! I will configure it! By the way, the issue has been resolved! I hadn't passed the child attributes of address, that's why this problem was occurring @miken32

Comment: Thank you for your help @miken32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `address` parameter is expected to have nested child parameters for each of `line1`,`city`, etc.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=php#create_customer-address

Answer (score 0):

You can check the developer logs in your Stripe account, which should give you a more details explanation of the error on the right side of the page.